# Sending an image from server to client (Python+Java)

Tags: java, python, image, sockets, server

I wrote a code few days ago that enables the client (on Java) to send an image to the server(on Python) and save it as a blob format in mysql. How can I do this in reverse? How can I send a picture from the server on python to the client on java ( with socket , for example ?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send picture from the server. You can write a client which will retrieve picture from the server.
[SimpleHTTPserver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) in Python can answer the url with image. 
[Reading Image with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986891/how-can-i-read-image-from-url-in-java) is even more easier. Use url what python provides and save it with Java.

Comment: Why not?   I don't think he's saying it has to be over HTTP.

Comment: Servers send things to clients all the time, without having to receive a request first.

Comment: That would be something new for me. [The client process always initiates a connection to the server, while the server process always waits for requests from any client.](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-server)

Comment: You're getting caught up on the nomenclature.  The point is his Python program *can* open a connection to the Java program.   The fact that one is a server for some things doesn't mean it can't be a client for others.

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with client sending "show picture" and the server's response is the picture ? Why can't this work ?