# How to blur a portion of an image with JAVA

Tags: java, image-processing, blur

How to blur a portion of an image, to hide some privates parts like credit card informations.

I try to use ConvolveOp.class like :

```
float[] matrix = new float[400];
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    matrix[i] = 1.0f/500.0f;

BufferedImage sourceImage =  (BufferedImage) image; ;
BufferedImage destImage = null ;
BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(20, 20, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null );
BufferedImage blurredImage = op.filter(sourceImage, destImage);
```

it seems to work, except that the image is completely blurred.

Comment: I can't really help you, that being said I just wanted to chime in and tell you that your question actually taught me something about Convolving images and blurring, so thanks for that ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this can be done by changing the matrix values, but this should definitely be possible by filtering a subimage, since, according to the [`BufferedImage.getSubimage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage-int-int-int-int-) documentation:

> The returned `BufferedImage` shares the same data array as the original image.

So the **original** `BufferedImage` should change with code like this:

```
BufferedImage image = /* ... */;
BufferedImage subImage = image.getSubimage(10, 20, 30, 40); // x, y, width, height
new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(20, 20, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null).filter(subImage, subImage);
```

I didn't test this though, and I can imagine that `filter` doesn't work as expected if `source` and `destination` are the same, in which case you could use a copy of the subimage, using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514158/2302862):

```
BufferedImage image = /* ... */;
BufferedImage dest = image.getSubimage(10, 20, 30, 40);  // x, y, width, height
ColorModel cm = dest.getColorModel();
BufferedImage src = new BufferedImage(cm, dest.copyData(dest.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster()), cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null).getSubimage(0, 0, dest.getWidth(), dest.getHeight());
new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(20, 20, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null).filter(src, dest);
```

After that, continue working with `image` (**not** `subImage`, `src` or `dest`!)

Comment: This solution cuts the image into two parts.
is it  possible to merge then ?

Comment: What do you mean "into two parts"? A blurred area and a non-blurred area? Or what exactly happens? Because as I said, I didn't test this.

Comment: Yes the blurred area and a non-blurred area are separated.

Comment: But like... next to each other, or one actually inside the other?

Comment: sorry for the quality of my English. So, the problem is that I do not know how to save the changes on the image. I try to create a new image (with the blur), however it save only a part of the image (blurred area) !!!

Comment: Try saving `image` itself - it should change.

Comment: it does not work like that. We must save the buffredImage. AS      <code>BufferedImage blurredImage = op.filter(subImage, null);
ImageIO.write(blurredImage, "jpg", new File(".../image.jpg"));</code>

Comment: Dude. You have a `BufferedImage` called `image`. And you have a part of that, also a `BufferedImage` called `subImage`. You are obviously saving `subImage`. I'm telling you to save `image` instead. Because `subImage` and `image` share the same array of pixels, `image` should change as well, when `subImage` is filtered.

Answer (score 3):

In the case you want to focus on the application and not on the specifics of image processing, you can use an image processing framework like [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/). Thus, you can do more with less code.

**Input image:**

[image]

**Output image:**

[image]

**Source code:**

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class PortionBlur {
    public PortionBlur(){
        // 1. Load image
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/credit_card.jpg");

        // 2. Create masks for each blurred region
        MarvinImageMask mask1 = new MarvinImageMask(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 38,170,345,24);
        MarvinImageMask mask2 = new MarvinImageMask(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 52,212,65,24);
        MarvinImageMask mask3 = new MarvinImageMask(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 196,212,65,20);
        MarvinImageMask mask4 = new MarvinImageMask(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 38,240,200,20);

        // 3. Process Image with each mask
        GaussianBlur gaussianBlur = new GaussianBlur();
        gaussianBlur.load();
        gaussianBlur.attributes.set("radius",15);

        gaussianBlur.process(image.clone(), image, mask1);
        gaussianBlur.process(image.clone(), image, mask2);
        gaussianBlur.process(image.clone(), image, mask3);
        gaussianBlur.process(image.clone(), image, mask4);

        // 4. Save the final image
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/credit_card_out.jpg");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PortionBlur();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**Gaussian blur algorithm source code:**

https://github.com/gabrielarchanjo/marvinproject/blob/master/marvinproject/dev/MarvinPlugins/src/org/marvinproject/image/blur/gaussianBlur/GaussianBlur.java

Comment: but what is the gaussianBlur method in this case ?

Comment: gaussianBlur(input_image, output_image, radius, pixels_mask) blurs the image using a Gaussian function. Gaussian Blur on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur

Comment: can you give us an example of this method using java ?

Comment: accourding to your recent changes, I edited your answer

Comment: It's not safe to use for real cards, because Gaussian blur can be reversed.

Comment: You suggest what, for a safe use?

Comment: @GabrielAmbrósioArchanjo is it possible to retrieve an image from a URL ? like  `MarvinImageIO.loadImage("URL");`

Comment: @KarimOukara You can request an image from URL, create a BufferedImage and then create a MarvinImage using the constructor new MarvinImage(BufferedImage). Loading image from URL in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986891/how-can-i-read-image-from-url-in-java